# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock doesnot open window in specified sizes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Hello everyone iam trying to open a aspx page in a dialog box window from asp button click event but even after specifying the dialog height and dialog width i want i could see dialog window opening in a default size.It seems like the height and width parameters i am passing are ignored.

**Here is the Server Side Code:**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "try { showMessageRulesDialog('MessageRuleCenterFrame.htm', true); }catch(e){alert(e);}", true);
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function showMessageRulesDialog(dialogName, refresh) 
{
try {

    var WinSettings =       "wcenter:yes;resizable:no;onscroll:off;dialogHeight:700px;dialogWidth:610px;";
    var ret = window.showModalDialog("../Dialogs/" + dialogName,"", WinSettings);
    if (refresh) {
        window.location = window.location;
    }
}
catch (e)
{ alert("ShowDialog Error: " + e); }
}
```

**HtmPage Properties**

```
<iframe src="MessageRulesCenter.aspx"  style="height:700px;width:610px;" frameborder="0"   scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

**MessageRulesCenter.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MessageRulesCenter.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Dialogs_QuotaCenter" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<%--<base target="_blank" /> --%>
<title>Quota Message Center</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Skins/QuotaCenter.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Common.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #form1
    {
        height: 450px;
        width: 581px;
    }
     .formfield * {
         vertical-align: middle;
         border-width:0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align: left">
<form id="form1" runat="server">      
    <table style="height: 437px; width: 582px"  >
        <tr>
           <td bgcolor="#91ACFF">

              <div class="Section" id="Sec1">                      
                <div>
                  <br /> &nbsp;
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Text="Message Rule Name : " 
                   ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="False"></asp:Label>                     
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtRuleName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                   <br /><br />
                </div>

                <div>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
                  Text="Create Message Rule On :" Font-Bold="False"></asp:Label>                      
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>                    

              </div>

              <div class="Section" id="Sec2">

                <div>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoIncoming" GroupName="MessageRules" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
                      Text="Incoming Message" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        oncheckedchanged="rdoOutgoing_CheckedChanged" />
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoOutgoing" GroupName="MessageRules"  runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
                      Text="Outgoing Message" oncheckedchanged="rdoOutgoing_CheckedChanged" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" />
                    <br />
                  <br />
                </div> 
                <div>
                    &nbsp; 
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Where"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div>
                   <p class="formfield">
                         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="lblField1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="From field Contains :"></asp:Label>
                         &nbsp;
                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtField3" runat="server" Width="272px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                       <asp:Button ID="btnAddContact" runat="server" Text="Add Contact" Width="102px" onclick="btnAddContact_Click"/>                   

                       <br />    
                  </p>              
               </div>

               <div>
                 <p class="formfield"> 
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <asp:Label ID="lblFiled2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Subject Contains :"></asp:Label>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtField4" runat="server" Width="270px"></asp:TextBox>
                 <br /> 
                 </p>
              </div>

             </div>
             <div class="Section" id ="Sec3">  

                <div>
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;                     
                     <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Then"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                 <div>
                     <p class="formfield">
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                         <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoMove" runat="server" GroupName ="ActionType" ForeColor="Black" Text="Move it to the Folder : " />
                  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMove" runat="server" Width="165px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlMove_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                     </p>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                     <p class="formfield">
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                         <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoCopy" runat="server" GroupName ="ActionType" ForeColor="Black" Text="Copy it to the Folder : " />
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCopy" runat="server" Width="165px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlMove_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                     </p>
                 </div>
                 <div style="text-align:right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <p class="formfield">                           
                     <asp:Button ID="btnDone" runat="server" Text="Done" OnClick="btnDone_Click" Width="61px" />
                     <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Cancel" />
                    </p>
                 </div>                    
              </div>               

           </td>
          </tr>

       </table>      
</form>
```

Comment: Your showMessageRulesDialog function is working for me as expected in ie9 and chrome. What browser you are using for debug and test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems it works fine. My guess for why it is not working as expected could be because of the browser version.

Check if you get the required behavior if you remove the Doctype declaration (the top most line in the page).